# Get all information on 1 QueryDjango

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am trying to get all values in a single queryset, i have the following model:

```
class Temporal(model.Models):
   id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
   value=models.CharField(max_length=60)
   created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   date_start = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   date_end = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   rate_name = models.ForeignKeyField("RateName")
   concept_payment = models.CharField(max_length=60)

   order = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and some other fields...

I am getting all the differents concept_payment this way:

```
 energy_concepts = Temporal.objects.filter(rate_name=rate_name,
                                                  date_start__month__lte=month_apply,
                                                   date_end__month__gte=month_apply,
                                                   concept_payment='Energy').first()

demand_concepts = Temporal.objects.filter(rate_name=rate_name,
                                               date_start__month__lte=month_apply,
                                               date_end__month__gte=month_apply,
                                               concept_payment='Demand').first()

other_concepts = Temporal.objects.filter(rate_name=rate_name,
                                              date_start__month__lte=month_apply,
                                              date_end__month__gte=month_apply,
                                              concept_payment='Others').first()

taxes_concepts = Temporal.objects.filter(rate_name=rate_name,
                                              date_start__month__lte=month_apply,
                                              date_end__month__gte=month_apply,
                                              concept_payment='Taxes').first()
```

and so on... where the only difference is the concept_payment, So I was wonder if there is a way to get them all, using annotate instead of getting one by one, by the way the concept_payment sis dynamic so I think I would have to get all the difference concepts first.
Thanks in advance.

Any direction or suggestions would be very helpful, my main concern is the fact every filter hits the database, which I believe is not very efficient.

Comment: You used `first()` in all of them. Is it mandatory or anything in the filtered result can be used?

Comment: Are you using postgres? There's a way to do it in one query if you are

Comment: Yes I am using postgres, but I Rather get them on single query using ORM on django, or is that what you meant?

Comment: Ok I'll add an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use django's [`in_bulk`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in-bulk) to give you a dictionary with the `concept_payment` as the key, and a `Temporal` instance as the value.

This would be tricky since there can be more than one instance per `concept_type`, but since you are using postgres and you said it doesn't matter which instance is returned, then you can use distinct with `concept_payment` to remove duplicates.

So try with:

```py
Temporal.objects.filter(
    rate_name=rate_name,
    date_start__month__lte=month_apply,
    date_end__month__gte=month_apply,
    concept_payment__in=['Taxes', 'Others', 'Demand', 'Energy'],
).distinct('concept_payment').in_bulk(field_name='concept_payment')
```

This should return something like:

```
{
    'Taxes': '<Temporal object with Taxes concept_type>',
    'Demand': '<Temporal object with Demand concept_type>',
    'Energy': '<Temporal object with Energy concept_type>',
    'Others': '<Temporal object with Others concept_type>',
}
```